# Eloquent ORM: Complex left join insists on using value as column name

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following Eloquent Query in one of my Models:

```
    return self::where('sequence', '=', $sequence)->where('interval', '=', $minutes)
        ->leftJoin('wallet', 'wallet_stats.wallet_id', '=', 'wallet.id')
        ->leftJoin('balance', function($join) use ($uid)
        {
            $join->on('balance.wallet_id', '=', 'wallet_stats.wallet_id')
                 ->on('balance.user_id', '=', $uid);
        })
        ->orderBy('volume', 'ASC')->get(['symbol', 'name', 'volume', 'start_price', 'end_price']);
```

The problem I'm having with this is the following error message:

> Oops! SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in
>   'on clause' (SQL: select `symbol`, `name`, `volume`, `start_price`,
>   `end_price` from `wallet_stats` left join `wallet` on
>   `wallet_stats`.`wallet_id` = `wallet`.`id` left join `balance` on
>   `balance`.`wallet_id` = `wallet_stats`.`wallet_id` and
>   `balance`.`user_id` = `2` where `sequence` = 0 and `interval` = 1440
>   order by `volume` asc)

For some reason Eloquent insists on using the value of $uid (in the 2nd "on" join condition) as a column name rather than a literal value.

Does anybody know how to get around that and have it accept a literal value in such a join specification?

Comment: Replace second `on` with `where`.

Comment: That works from a syntax perspective but changes the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite seem to replicate your error however this is what I've used in past instances. Giedrius Kiršys' suggestion in the comment on your question is also good.

```
 return self::where('sequence', '=', $sequence)->where('interval', '=', $minutes)
        ->leftJoin('wallet', 'wallet_stats.wallet_id', '=', 'wallet.id')
        ->leftJoin('balance', function($join) use ($uid)
        {
            $join->on('balance.wallet_id', '=', 'wallet_stats.wallet_id')
                 ->on('balance.user_id', '=', \DB::raw($uid));
        })
        ->orderBy('volume', 'ASC')->get(['symbol', 'name', 'volume', 'start_price', 'end_price']);
```

This assumes you haven't already imported `DB`, if you have get rid of the `\`

Answer (score 1):

**Use  ->where() for 2nd on clause, such as**

```
    ->leftJoin('balance', function($join) use ($uid)
    {
        $join->on('balance.wallet_id', '=', 'wallet_stats.wallet_id');
        $join->where('balance.user_id','=', $uid);
    })
```

**Or, use the DB::raw() for on clause value**

```
   ->leftJoin('balance', function($join) use ($uid)
    {
        $join->on('balance.wallet_id', '=', 'wallet_stats.wallet_id');
        $join->on('balance.user_id', '=', DB::raw($uid));
    })
```

Comment: It has been helpful for me.